# javascript not able to detect right click and delete and cut text

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox and save button. If anything changed on textbox then only save button should be enabled. I am able to take care this using javascript event, but when i select some text and right click and delete that selected text then, I do not get any event. Below is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var hiddenfield = document.getElementById("hide").value;
                var textboxval = document.getElementById("me").value;

                if (textboxval != hiddenfield) {
                    document.getElementById("xx").disabled = false;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("xx").disabled = true;
                }
            }

            function load() {
                document.getElementById("hide").value = document.getElementById("me").value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load();">
        <input id="me" type="text" value="test test" onkeyup="myFunction()" onmouseup="myFunction()"
        onmousedown="myFunction()">
        <input type="button" id="xx" value="Save" disabled="disabled" />
        <br>
        <input id="hide" type="hidden" value="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there way to detect if user delete the text via right button click?

Comment: I found the answer, onmouseout and onmousemove is best way to handle cntext-menu control change

Answer (score 1):

Try `onchange`, since the context-menu control changes the contents.

Comment: no , it does not work.. select text and right click with mouse and delete keep the focus on textbox and does not perform any action

Comment: I found the answer, onmouseout and onmousemove is best way to handle cntext-menu control change –